# Form.show and Form.Hide time interval Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, timer

Hi a good day to all of you I have this program that is a trivia game in which I want to put a  form as a splash screen by having a form.show() and form.hide and I want to ask how can I set the form by showing it for atleast 3 seconds and hide it again? Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then

        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()
        correctmsg.Hide()

        Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"
        Return 'Don't do any more checks this time around

    ElseIf Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" Then
        'Reason ElseIf (In case the question was 'who invented the telephone' then the first errormessage should not not be shown)
        wrongmsg.Show()
        Return

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put timer `timer1` on `splashscreenFORM` set it to `enabled=false`
double click on `timer1` put this code on it `me.close()`

now from the form where u want to do that

```
dim mysplash as new splashscreenFORM 
mysplash.timer1.Interval = 3000
mysplash.timer1.start()
mysplash.show()
```

the splash form should appears for 3 sec

Comment: @user3231002, if this answers you're question, then you should mark it as so, so that other users with the same question can see the answer, and also so that ppl are willing to help you in the future.

Comment: @davidsbro ok sir because I am just new here I did not know how to mark :p

Comment: @user3231002, you're fine, I knew you were new, that's why I commented that. :) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Public tTimer As Timer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    tTimer = New Timer()
    tTimer.Interval = 3000
    tTimer.Enabled = False
    AddHandler tTimer.Tick, AddressOf OnLayouttimerTick
End Sub

 Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then

    Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

    correctmsg.Show()
    tTimer.Start()

    Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"
    Return 'Don't do any more checks this time around

ElseIf Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" Then
    'Reason ElseIf (In case the question was 'who invented the telephone' then the first errormessage should not not be shown)
    wrongmsg.Show()
    Return

End If

 Private Sub OnLayouttimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    correctmsg.Hide()
 End Sub
```

Comment: This method have one problem. If someone clicks the button again before the correctmsg form is closed, the second time it will get close before 3s

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.sleep(3000)` if you don't want your GUI to do anything else. If you want your GUI to function normally when this `correctmsg` form is shown, use the following code

```
correctmsg.Show()

Dim SW2 As New Stopwatch
    SW2.Start()
    Do
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until SW2.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000m
correctmsg.Hide()
```